Strapi APIPopulate
I was using populate deep in URL and it was working fine but since yesterday the components which are used in other components their media field is not populating, I don't know why this happen suddenly.
URL:
http://localhost:1337/api/projects?filters[name][$eq]=Talent Dove & populate=deep
Here in components banners.banner-1 under items there is one field name image which is a media field which is not showing - title & description field are showing but not the image field:
Response:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Talent Dove",
                "createdAt": "2024-07-26T10:46:48.217Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-07-26T10:46:58.233Z",
                "publishedAt": "2024-07-26T10:46:57.915Z",
                "primarycolor": "#F9A214",
                "secondarycolor": null,
                "common_header": true,
                "common_footer": true,
                "pages": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": 11,
                            "attributes": {
                                "name": "Home",
                                "link": "/",
                                "createdAt": "2024-07-26T10:49:45.987Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2024-07-26T11:19:11.802Z",
                                "publishedAt": "2024-07-26T10:50:08.478Z",
                                "components": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 9,
                                        "__component": "headers.header-1",
                                        "theme": "primarycolor",
                                        "type": "Header 2",
                                        "logo": {
                                            "data": {
                                                "id": 14,
                                                "attributes": {
                                                    "name": "icon.png",
                                                    "alternativeText": null,
                                                    "caption": null,
                                                    "width": 574,
                                                    "height": 374,
                                                    "formats": {
                                                        "small": {
                                                            "name": "small_icon.png",
                                                            "hash": "small_icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                                                            "ext": ".png",
                                                            "mime": "image/png",
                                                            "path": null,
                                                            "width": 500,
                                                            "height": 326,
                                                            "size": 58.38,
                                                            "sizeInBytes": 58379,
                                                            "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/small_icon_fdae7e0fa6.png"
                                                        },
                                                        "thumbnail": {
                                                            "name": "thumbnail_icon.png",
                                                            "hash": "thumbnail_icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                                                            "ext": ".png",
                                                            "mime": "image/png",
                                                            "path": null,
                                                            "width": 239,
                                                            "height": 156,
                                                            "size": 15.43,
                                                            "sizeInBytes": 15425,
                                                            "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/thumbnail_icon_fdae7e0fa6.png"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "hash": "icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                                                    "ext": ".png",
                                                    "mime": "image/png",
                                                    "size": 10.28,
                                                    "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/icon_fdae7e0fa6.png",
                                                    "previewUrl": null,
                                                    "provider": "aws-s3",
                                                    "provider_metadata": null,
                                                    "createdAt": "2024-07-19T12:13:15.566Z",
                                                    "updatedAt": "2024-07-19T12:13:15.566Z"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "NavItems": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 32,
                                                "name": "Home",
                                                "link": "/"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 33,
                                                "name": "About Us",
                                                "link": "/about"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 34,
                                                "name": "Products",
                                                "link": "/product"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 35,
                                                "name": "Gallery",
                                                "link": "/gallery"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 36,
                                                "name": "Contact Us",
                                                "link": "/contact"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 6,
                                        "__component": "banners.banner-1",
                                        "type": "Banner 1",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 1,
                                                "title": "First Title",
                                                "description": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo."
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 7,
                                        "__component": "footers.footer-1",
                                        "description": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
                                        "organization_name_copyright": "Talent Dove",
                                        "theme": "primarycolor",
                                        "type": "Footer 2",
                                        "logo": {
                                            "data": {
                                                "id": 22,
                                                "attributes": {
                                                    "name": "td_white_logo1.png",
                                                    "alternativeText": null,
                                                    "caption": null,
                                                    "width": 1619,
                                                    "height": 471,
                                                    "formats": {
                                                        "thumbnail": {
                                                            "name": "thumbnail_td_white_logo1.png",
                                                            "hash": "thumbnail_td_white_logo1_70a697cb07",
                                                            "ext": ".png",
                                                            "mime": "image/png",
                                                            "path": null,
                                                            "width": 245,
                                                            "height": 71,
                                                            "size": 6.42,
                                                            "sizeInBytes": 6418,
                                                            "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/thumbnail_td_white_logo1_70a697cb07.png"
                                                        },
                                                        "large": {
                                                            "name": "large_td_white_logo1.png",
                                                            "hash": "large_td_white_logo1_70a697cb07",
                                                            "ext": ".png",
                                                            "mime": "image/png",
                                                            "path": null,
                                                            "width": 1000,
                                                            "height": 291,
                                                            "size": 36.3,
                                                            "sizeInBytes": 36300,
                                                            "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/large_td_white_logo1_70a697cb07.png"
                                                        },
                                                        "medium": {
                                                            "name": "medium_td_white_logo1.png",
                                                            "hash": "medium_td_white_logo1_70a697cb07",
                                                            "ext": ".png",
                                                            "mime": "image/png",
                                                            "path": null,
                                                            "width": 750,
                                                            "height": 218,
                                                            "size": 25.65,
                                                            "sizeInBytes": 25654,
                                                            "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/medium_td_white_logo1_70a697cb07.png"
                                                        },
                                                        "small": {
                                                            "name": "small_td_white_logo1.png",
                                                            "hash": "small_td_white_logo1_70a697cb07",
                                                            "ext": ".png",
                                                            "mime": "image/png",
                                                            "path": null,
                                                            "width": 500,
                                                            "height": 145,
                                                            "size": 15.34,
                                                            "sizeInBytes": 15335,
                                                            "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/small_td_white_logo1_70a697cb07.png"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "hash": "td_white_logo1_70a697cb07",
                                                    "ext": ".png",
                                                    "mime": "image/png",
                                                    "size": 14.22,
                                                    "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/td_white_logo1_70a697cb07.png",
                                                    "previewUrl": null,
                                                    "provider": "aws-s3",
                                                    "provider_metadata": null,
                                                    "createdAt": "2024-07-20T12:30:06.949Z",
                                                    "updatedAt": "2024-07-20T12:30:46.454Z"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "Useful": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 13,
                                                "name": "Privacy Policy",
                                                "link": "/privacy"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 14,
                                                "name": "Terms & Conditions",
                                                "link": "/terms"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "Contact": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 16,
                                                "type": "email",
                                                "value": "info@td.com"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 17,
                                                "type": "phone",
                                                "value": "+91 999999999"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 18,
                                                "type": "address",
                                                "value": "Ahmedabad, Gujarat"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "social_media": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 10,
                                                "type": "facebook",
                                                "link": "#"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 11,
                                                "type": "x",
                                                "link": "#"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 12,
                                                "type": "linkedin",
                                                "link": "#"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "project": {
                                    "data": {
                                        "id": 8,
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "name": "Talent Dove",
                                            "createdAt": "2024-07-26T10:46:48.217Z",
                                            "updatedAt": "2024-07-26T10:46:58.233Z",
                                            "publishedAt": "2024-07-26T10:46:57.915Z",
                                            "primarycolor": "#F9A214",
                                            "secondarycolor": null,
                                            "common_header": true,
                                            "common_footer": true,
                                            "company_icon": {
                                                "data": {
                                                    "id": 14,
                                                    "attributes": {
                                                        "name": "icon.png",
                                                        "alternativeText": null,
                                                        "caption": null,
                                                        "width": 574,
                                                        "height": 374,
                                                        "formats": {
                                                            "small": {
                                                                "name": "small_icon.png",
                                                                "hash": "small_icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                                                                "ext": ".png",
                                                                "mime": "image/png",
                                                                "path": null,
                                                                "width": 500,
                                                                "height": 326,
                                                                "size": 58.38,
                                                                "sizeInBytes": 58379,
                                                                "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/small_icon_fdae7e0fa6.png"
                                                            },
                                                            "thumbnail": {
                                                                "name": "thumbnail_icon.png",
                                                                "hash": "thumbnail_icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                                                                "ext": ".png",
                                                                "mime": "image/png",
                                                                "path": null,
                                                                "width": 239,
                                                                "height": 156,
                                                                "size": 15.43,
                                                                "sizeInBytes": 15425,
                                                                "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/thumbnail_icon_fdae7e0fa6.png"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "hash": "icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                                                        "ext": ".png",
                                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                                        "size": 10.28,
                                                        "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/icon_fdae7e0fa6.png",
                                                        "previewUrl": null,
                                                        "provider": "aws-s3",
                                                        "provider_metadata": null,
                                                        "createdAt": "2024-07-19T12:13:15.566Z",
                                                        "updatedAt": "2024-07-19T12:13:15.566Z"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "company_icon": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": 14,
                        "attributes": {
                            "name": "icon.png",
                            "alternativeText": null,
                            "caption": null,
                            "width": 574,
                            "height": 374,
                            "formats": {
                                "small": {
                                    "name": "small_icon.png",
                                    "hash": "small_icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                                    "ext": ".png",
                                    "mime": "image/png",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 500,
                                    "height": 326,
                                    "size": 58.38,
                                    "sizeInBytes": 58379,
                                    "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/small_icon_fdae7e0fa6.png"
                                },
                                "thumbnail": {
                                    "name": "thumbnail_icon.png",
                                    "hash": "thumbnail_icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                                    "ext": ".png",
                                    "mime": "image/png",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 239,
                                    "height": 156,
                                    "size": 15.43,
                                    "sizeInBytes": 15425,
                                    "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/thumbnail_icon_fdae7e0fa6.png"
                                }
                            },
                            "hash": "icon_fdae7e0fa6",
                            "ext": ".png",
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "size": 10.28,
                            "url": "https://anriyo-cms-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/icon_fdae7e0fa6.png",
                            "previewUrl": null,
                            "provider": "aws-s3",
                            "provider_metadata": null,
                            "createdAt": "2024-07-19T12:13:15.566Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2024-07-19T12:13:15.566Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}

Image field is not showing
